# Pass data with segue without displaying screen

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I'm trying to achieve passing of data using segue, but without displaying the screen. There are two view controllers in my project and I will name them `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController`.

On `FirstViewController`, I am using `Show` Adaptive Segue to pass data using `performSegueWithIdentifier`. The `prepareForSegue` method will be called, and recognising the `identifier` I've set to display `SecondViewController`.

However, the problem is I do not want to display `SecondViewController`. There are other things that my users may want to do before heading for `SecondViewController`.

I'm new to iOS programming, and I only know passing of data with segue. Please do share with me if there are methods to pass data apart from segue.

**EDIT:** To further elaborate my question. I'm working with `TabBarController`, and both `View Controllers` are accessible on the Tab bar. So when I am on `SecondViewController` with some data already "segue-ed" over from `FirstViewController`, I can head back to `FirstViewController` to add more data. At `SecondViewController` with `UIRefreshControl` I need the updated  data.

Comment: Keep the data into a var, and when all is done, perform the segue and pass the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the segue in code you can do what you want in a following way

1) Instantiate view controller from the story board

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SecondViewController", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("set_it_in_IB") as! SecondViewController
```

2) Set the properties you need to set as the view controller is already instantiated

```
vc.someProperty = "asd"
```

3) Segue!

```
viewController.presentViewController(viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think your method may work. However just to clarify, I'm working with `TabBarController`, both View Controllers are accessible on the Tab bar. So when I am on `SecondViewController`, I head back to `FirstViewController` to add more data. At `SecondViewController` with `UIRefreshControl` will I get to see the updated data?

Answer (score 1):

From your user's perspective, they would not know whether the data is being updated before they segue or not, so it is probably fine to just pass the data with the `prepareFoSegue` function.

Otherwise, you could try setting a notification to the `viewDidLoad` on your `FirstViewController`and `SecondViewController` by

`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: nil, name: updateSecondVCNotification, object: nil)`

and posting the notification from the `FirstViewController` whenever the data needs to be updated using the

`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(updateSecondVCNotification, object: self)`

Then on second view controller set the the selector of the `addObserver` to a string of the name of whatever function you want it to do like `"reloadNewData"`

`func reloadNewData() {
        tableView.reloadData()
}`

Does this help? Don't forget to set the `updateSecondVCNotification` as a global string constant at the top of your `FirstViewController`. Learn more about `NSNotificationCenter` at https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/08/fundamentals-of-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift/

Woo! Notifications! ＼(＾▽＾)／

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that would work for you, but you could simply keep the data in memory of your FirstViewController for the time during which the user is still interacting and giving feedback and once it's done, send all the data to the SecondViewController through the segue.

Comment: Apologies. My question earlier wasn't clear enough. I've added more information to it.

Comment: In the case of tabs, I believe that simply passing data as you go would do the trick. Try doing let secondViewController = SecondViewController() and then secondViewController.whatever = ?//insert actual data transfer. Once you're in the other tab just refresh the data displayed